# What would make a thread to hung with the incorrect type conversion in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I recently happened to make a incorrect type conversion in Java - of converting Double to long. 
This type conversion code is part of a logic that runs as a separate thread (used singleThread of ExectorService). This thread runs indefinitely for every 30s. It has a infinite while loop that made to run every 30s.

When I executed this code to my surprise my Java code hung at the type conversion (conversion from Double to long) instead of throwing runtime error.

So, I was wondering what would make JVM to hung at the incorrect type conversion  ?

P.S: I'll try to paste my actual code.

**update:**

Below is the code that's executed by my the single threaded executorService.

```
void collectMetrics() {
     // Create the connection
     while(RETRY){ // Default RETRY is True 
         Long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         Socket connection = createConnection();

         if (connection == null){
             waitForSometime();
             continue;
         }
         // Get the output stream
         DataOutputStream outputStream = getDataOutputStream(connection);

         if (outputStream == null){
             waitForSometime();
             continue;
         }
         // Get metrics from JMX
         Map<String, Gauge> g = metricRegistry.getGauges();
         for(Entry<String, Gauge> e : g.entrySet()){
             String metricName = convertToMetricStandard(e.getKey());
             Long metricValue = (Long) e.getValue().getValue(); // CODE HUNGS HERE INDEFINITELY. 

             String metricToSend = String.format("%s %s %s\n", metricName, metricValue, currTime);
             LOGGER.debug("Metric to send - `{}`", metricToSend); // TODO: Remove
             try {
                 outputStream.writeBytes(metricToSend);
                 outputStream.flush();
                 // Remove the metric from JMX after successfully sending metric to graphite
                 removeMetricFromJMX(metricName);
             } catch (IOException e1) {
                 LOGGER.error("Unable to send metric to Graphite - ", e1.getMessage());
             }

         }

         closeOutputStream();
         closeConnection();

         waitForSometime();
     }
 }
```

So, basically my program hangs indefinitely at the improper conversion - `Long metricValue = (Long) e.getValue().getValue();`. `e.getValue().getValue()` here returns a `double` value but here I did conversion to `Long` instead of `String`.

**What does the above code do?**

- It collects metric data from JMX and sends it to graphite. (Default wait-time is 30 seconds.)

Comment: Difficult to say without the code. I guess you loop while that `long` has some value and the `Double` casting would auto-unbox to `long` and round down to 0 forever?

Comment: Not sure. Added the actual code.

Comment: Don't use `Long` when you can use `long`, and use `"%d"` instead of `"%s"`. Then split `e.getValue().getValue()` into `Gauge g = e.getValue(); long metricValue = g.getValue();` to isolate which is causing your thread to hang: it might be the `e.getValue()` as well, not necessarily the cast.
Then, if your thread is running in a `ScheduledExecutorService`, your `waitForSometime()` method could delay execution so much that you could have two instances running concurrently, which might cause a deadlock in `Gauge.getValue()` (depending on the Executor configuration).